# Lambdas operating on containers in sympy

Tags: python, lambda, sympy

I would like to do something like the following in sympy:

`In [1]: from sympy import symbols, Lambda
    In [2]: from sympy.core.containers import Dict
    In [3]: x, y = symbols('x y')
    In [4]: d = Dict({1:x, 2:y})
    In [5]: f = Lambda(d, d[1] + d[2])
    In [6]: f({1:10, 2:20})
    Out[6]: 30`

It seems like sympy's lambdas can only operate on symbols, however, and not containers. Is this possible? if so, how might I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make a Lambda, you'd need something unevaluated. `d[1]` evaluates right away to the value of the Dict (`x`).

As far as I know, there isn't such an object in SymPy already. IndexedBase would be the closest, but it's supposed to index into ordered containers, and doesn't really work to substitute an exact container anyway.

Here's a simple thing that seems to work. I'm not really sure if the evaluation logic in `UnevaluatedDict` is quite right. Also I didn't change the printers on `UnevaluatedDict` so that it prints as `d[1]` instead of `UnevaluatedDict(d, 1)`. Note that I had to employ a few tricks to get SymPy and Python to not think that `UnevaluatedDictBase` is iterable (otherwise things would try to do `for i in d` and get stuck in an infinite loop).

There are probably also way better names for these things (really `IndexedBase` should just work like this).

```
from sympy.core.compatibility import NotIterable

class UnevaluatedDictBase(Symbol, NotIterable):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return UnevaluatedDict(self, item)
        def __iter__(self):
            raise TypeError("UnevaluatedDictBase is not iterable")

class UnevaluatedDict(Expr):
    def __new__(cls, d, item):
        if hasattr(d, '__getitem__') and not isinstance(d, UnevaluatedDictBase):
            return d[item]
        return super(UnevaluatedDict, cls).__new__(cls, d, item)
```

This works like

```
In [35]: d = UnevaluatedDictBase('d')

In [36]: d[1]
Out[36]: UnevaluatedDict(d, 1)

In [37]: d[1].subs(d, {1: x})
Out[37]: x

In [61]: Lambda(d, d[1] + d[2])
Out[61]: d ↦ UnevaluatedDict(d, 1) + UnevaluatedDict(d, 2)

In [64]: l = Lambda(d, d[1] + d[2])

In [65]: l({1: x, 2: y})
Out[65]: x + y
```